# Question on graphing space curves in a plane

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, functions, curves, calculator

This is from Gilbert Strang's Calculus Book, on the section of partial derivatives.

[image]

I am not sure at all what this means. How can you graph 3 variables in a TI-81 calculator (which is what I assume he is referring to). What space curve is he even trying to graph in the first place?

Comment: Plot in parametric mode, perhaps...

Comment: @SeanRoberson how can I do that? I'm just confused because doesn't parametric mode require common variable t? But the equations here all involve x,y,z.

Comment: Is there anything before this passage? This feels isolated so I can't say for sure (assume nobody else has the book).